# 2 samples hypothesis testing in Python

Tags: python, r, statistics, hypothesis-test

I am endeavouring to perform a two sample hypothesis test in Python, having been given the original code in R.

The code in R is:-

```
    prop.test(x=c(10,16), n=c(100,100))`
```

#The p-value is 0.2931, being greater than alpha=0.5,
#so we fail to reject the null hypothesis

I have tried to perform the same test in both scipy and statsmodels libraries.

The code using scipy is:-

```
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.stats as stats

    hats = np.array([[100,10], [100, 16]])
    print("Hats scipy: ", stats.chi2_contingency(hats))`
#The p-value .368767 is greater than alpha=0.5, so we fail to reject the null hypothesis
```

The code using statsmodels is:-

```
    import numpy as np
    import statsmodels.stats.proportion as proportion

    hat_a = 10
    hat_b = 16
    sample_a = 100
    sample_b = 100
    hats = np.array([hat_a, hat_b])
    samples = np.array([sample_a,sample_b])

    chisq, pvalue, table = proportion.proportions_chisquare(hats, samples)
    print('Results are ','chisq =%.3f, pvalue = %.3f'%(chisq, pvalue))
```

#The p-value .207 is greater than alpha=0.5, so we fail to reject the null hypothesis

I would like to say that I have researched the internet looking for the correct way to perform the 2 sample hypothesis test and have found a variety of ways to code this request using both scipy and statsmodels.

My question is:-
Is there a hypothesis test I can perform in statsmodels or scipy that will give me the same result that I achieved using R, which is a p-value of 0.2931.

I am new to statistics and probabilities, so any advice would be greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: The statsmodels unit tests use R prop.test with `correct=FALSE` to compare the results. statsmodels functions don't use continuity correction

Comment: Note: some methods for two sample proportion hypothesis tests recommended in the literature are in https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.test_proportions_2indep.html Those are better than chisquare test  (I don't know what the R equivalents are)

Answer (score 0):

R's `prop.test` uses the Yates continuity correction by default (it can be turned off using `correct=F`)

Therefore, to replicate in python, you need to use that Yates continuity correction. This can be done with `stats.chi2_contingency()`. However, your array of observed values needs to be adjusted, so that the number in each cell of an RxC table (in this case, 2x2) is reflected.

```
hats = np.array([[90,10], [84, 16]])
stats.chi2_contingency(hats, correction=True)[1]
```

Output:

```
0.2931241173597945
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it with correction=True and it works.